# FutureProvider gives null to a listener

Tags: flutter, future, flutter-provider

I recognize `FutureProvider` can be used when a model will be given by a `Future`. It is needed to initialize the model by its `init() async` method, so I tried `FutureProvider`. However `FutureProvider` didn't give an instance of the model. It had given `null`.

Additionally while using `ChangeNotifierProvider` successfully updates UI, `FutureProvider` seems to not update UI when the `notifyListeners()` is called. `Consumer` gives same result. Is there anything to be fixed? Thank you.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class MyModel extends ChangeNotifier {
 int _point = 0;

 int get point => _point;

 set point(int value) {
   if (_point != value) {
     _point = value;
     notifyListeners();
   }
 }

 Future<void> init() async { /* Use await doSomething(); */ }
}

void main() => runApp(
  FutureProvider<MyModel>(
    create: (context) async {
      final model = MyModel();
      await model.init();
      return Future.value(model);
    },
    lazy: false,
    updateShouldNotify: (_, __) => true,
    child: MyHomePage(),
  ), 
);

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final model = Provider.of<MyModel>(context);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            '${model.point}',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            model.point++;
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: not sure if this is what you're trying to achieve, but have a look at how I combined features of FutureProvider (waiting for async data) and ChangeNotifierProvider (change data and provide on request with notifyListeners()) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72533330/how-to-combine-features-of-futureprovider-futurebuilder-waiting-for-async-data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ChangeNotifierProvider`. It will update your UI whenever `notifyListeners` is called.

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (context) => MyModel()..init(), 
  child: MyHomePage(),
)
```

There is actually no need to call `init` if you are not doing anything inside your init method.

And if your `MyModel` class is only there for a single int value, you don't even need to use it. You can do something like:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<ValueNotifier<int>>(
  create: (context) => ValueNotifier<int>(0),
  child: MyHomePage(),
);
```

And inside your HomePage

```
final counter = Provider.of<ValueNotifier<int>>(context);
```

You can use it inside your `Text` widget like:

```
Text('${counter.value}')
```

Comment: OK, certainly `ChangeNotifierProvider` gives the model and updates UI properly. But I need to execute `await model.init();` while the sample don't include any real initialization. My question is why the sample code gives `null` to `Provider.of<MyModel>(context)`. `ChangeNotifierProvider` cannot be used in this case because Future<MyModel> must be provided.

Comment: Since `FutureProvider` listens for a Future, it gives null(I guess). You are trying to avoid using `model.init()` is that correct?

Comment: No, `model.init()` must be executed in this case.